# Hide some controls video tag on Iphone

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem with a video on my site;
I need to hide the video timeline and show the audio icon.
i used this code

```css
video#mobile::-webkit-media-controls-timeline, video#mobile::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider, video#mobile::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display, video#mobile::-webkit-media-controls-play-button, video#mobile::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {
    display: none !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
```

```html
<video id="mobile" width="100%" height="100%" disablepictureinpicture controlslist="nodownload" controls controlslist="nofullscreen nodownload noremoteplayback foobar" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" playsinline=""> <source src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/VIDEO-MEEDYA-MUSICA-1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

but the result on IOs devices is as follows

[image]

but i want this:

[image]

thank you to all

Comment: This should help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh924823(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN